# Diffusion of FAD+

Tags: biochemistry, cell-biology, cellular-respiration

Why is NAD+ free to diffuse within the mitochondrion whereas FAD+ is not ? What biochemical properties cause this difference ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained at [the Wikipedia page for succinate dehydrogenase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Succinate_dehydrogenase#Redox_centers) the FAD is covalently attached to one of the subunits of the protein. It is the first carrier in a short **intramolecular** redox chain involving Fe-S clusters, and possibly a haem, before the electrons derived from succinate are passed on to ubiquinone and on down the respiratory chain.

As you say, this contrasts with NAD which is a diffusible coenzyme.